# make a series of column header for dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python coding, this might be a very rudimentary question. I am preparing a data that has different errors of estimates taken at different time frames. So I need a column header that looks like D300 D600 D900 .. .. for a dataframe. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You can simply rename the dataframe's columns with: `df.columns = ['D300', 'D600'...]`

Comment: its a very long list going to D15,600. I was wondering if there might be an easier method that can create a list.

Comment: You can leverage the range function in python. `df.columns = [f'D{x}' for x in range(0, 901, 300)][1:]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on Michael's comment, you can use `range` and `list comprehension`:

```
# just to make things explicit
start = 300
end = 15600
# +1 to end since range ends aren't inclusive
df.columns = [f'{x} for x in range(start, end+1, 300)]
```